# Group policies not being applied

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy

I have 3 Group Policies set, and I wish to apply them as follows -

- Default Domain Policy - Every logon
- RDP File - Only when logging on to a machine in the `dynedrewett.com\DD\Workstations\` OU
- Folder Redirection - Only when logging on to a machine in the `dynedrewett.com\DD\Workstations\` OU

However, when I log on to a workstation, only the Default Domain Policy is applied.

If I move the other GPO's to the same location, they are then applied (but to every logon, which I do not want).

Can anyone suggest why they may not be getting picked up (they are not found, as opposed to not applied due to permissions)? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Run a GP modeling wizard or `gpresults /v` to find out what is and isn't being applied and why.
2. Make sure you are applying them correctly.  If it is a user settings GPO then it needs to be applied/linked to the OU where the user accounts reside.  If it is a computer settings GPO then it needs to be applied to the OU where the computer accounts that will get the GPO reside.  If you need to apply a user setting GPO to a set of computers then you need to look into `loopback processing`.
3. Make sure the access rights are correct.  If it is a computer settings GPO make sure the computer accounts (or domain computers) have rights to the GPO and to the location (NTFS/share rights) of the GPO if it is running a script/access files.

Comment: Great, it looks like `Loopback Processing` is the key here, and the GPO's are showing up as applied in GP Modling (which I should have mentioned that I did try before posting). Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @DavidGard Make sure you get the difference between `merge` & `replace` if you're going to play with loopback

Comment: @Dan - Thanks, I think I'm good with that. I want the User policies defined in this GPO to supersede others when users log on to the servers it is applied to. Therefore I'm using Replace. Thanks.